# find and replace a string using regular expression

Tags: regex

i need to find

```
sessionOpen(0, (int *)(&SessionId));
```

and replace the same as follows,

```
sessionOpen(
\#if USE_MULTIPLE_DB
              0,
\#endif
 (int *)(&SessionId));
```

how can i achieve this using regular expression search and replace method????

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619851/remove-empty-lines-in-eclipse-code-editior-by-find-replace-ctrlf for possible help.

Answer (score 1):

replace `sessionOpen\((0), \(int \*\)\(&SessionId\)\);`

with `sessionOpen(\n#if USE_MULTIPLE_DB $1, #endif\n(int *)(&SessionId))`

(I assume you want to capture the zero `0`)

Comment: Thank u for answer, but i need to add a new line after '#if" and '#endif' bt '\n' is not working ??

Comment: when i am trying to replace this string as u told, i got an error as follows, "incompatible line delimiter near index 83396" in eclipse. please help me to solve this problem. ??